# Node group asset, all paras work fine apart from the colour ramp

Tags: materials, asset-browser, asset

I am creating an asset node group (metal generator) in one file and want to import it as an asset into another file. This all works fine apart from the color ramp para.

Here is the setup I have in the file where I am creating the node group asset. Now, this does work correctly. When I adjust the ColorRampRoughnessAdjustor, it works as expected. I have marked this as an asset. I created a para for the color ramp, set from 0 to 1 as a float. Copied it as New driver and pasted it in the Pos of the colour ramp.

[image]

Okay, now in another file, I have created a new material, opened up my asset browser and dropped in my node asset. It is worth mentioning, in the asset browser, I have the dropdown set to link. As for my metal generator asset, all values are the same but the color ramp para does not work. When I adjust the slider, it does not change the value.

[image]

Any ideas on the potential issue?

Comment: Hello ! The simple answer is that AFAIK drivers don't get copied over with assets. If you're using a color ramp for 0 to 1 mapping, you can replace it with a Map Range node and directly plug the values into the inputs. Please add a screenshot of the content of the node group for further information

Comment: @Gorgious Makes complete sense and I got it working as wanted, thank you Gorgious. ευχαριστώ φίλε